# Python / Boto3: Float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using Python 3.7 to store data in a DynamoDB database and encountering the following error message when I try and write an item to the database:

```
Float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead.
```

My code:

```
ddb_table = my_client.Table(table_name)

with ddb_table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for item in items:
        item_to_put: dict = json.loads(json.dumps(item), parse_float=Decimal)

        # Send record to database.
        batch.put_item(Item=item_to_put)
```

"items" is a list of Python dicts. If I print out the types of the "item_to_put" dict, they are all of type str.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What exactly is `item_to_put`?

Comment: @Marcin It's a dict containing the items that I wish to add to the DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ran into the same issue and it turned out that Python was passing a string parameter as something else. The issue went away when I wrapped all of the items in str().

Comment: Yes, I had to do something like this, which is less than ideal:

    item_to_put: dict = {}

    for item_key in item:
        item_to_put[item_key] = str(item[item_key])

Comment: You should keep the types when possible. Check the 
M S R's solution

Answer (score 50):

Convert all the float to the Decimal

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal
item = json.loads(json.dumps(item), parse_float=Decimal)

table.put_item(
    Item=item
)
```

Comment: Hm, I'm getting TypeError('Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable')

Comment: This doesn't seem to be any different to the code in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the value as a Number type in DynamoDB, then you just need to convert the float to a Decimal. For example, if using the boto3 Table resource:

```
import boto3
from decimal import Decimal

dyn = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
SOME_TABLE = dyn.Table(SOME_TABLE_NAME)

percent = 1.234
item = {
        ...
        'percent': Decimal(str(percent))
        ...
    }

SOME_TABLE.put_item(Item=item)
```

Why doesn't Decimal do the str conversion for you? Got me. Maybe they'll fix it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. In my case it was because some of my records did not have a certain key, and that key was being auto-added with nan by default(I guess?). I added some simple logic to check if that key was a list and set it to an empty list if not before running `batch.put_item` which has seemingly satisfied the Dynamo beast.

Answer (score -1):

Add: from decimal import Decimal
above the expression. This should fix the problem

Comment: The import was already there; implied in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Solution drawing from [MattC's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78104602/9855567) and using the `decimal` module (as the question was already doing):

```
import boto3
from decimal import Decimal

my_client = boto3.resource("dynamodb")

# float (to str) to Decimal parser to avoid DynamoDB errors
def parse_float(value):
    return Decimal(str(value))

ddb_table = my_client.Table(table_name)

with ddb_table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for item in items:
        item_to_put: dict = json.loads(json.dumps(item), parse_float=parse_float)
    # Send record to database.
    batch.put_item(Item=item_to_put)
```

Not to confuse anyone, it's worth mentioning the difference between a boto3 [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource) and [client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client): [Boto 3: Resource vs Client](https://www.learnaws.org/2021/02/24/boto3-resource-client/)

Context of the issue and other workarounds:

[Add ability to disable Decimal usage for DynamoDB number type.](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/369)

[How can I store 30.40 in DynamoDb?](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/665)